# I need to write code in python for comparing text of two documents using fingerprint techniques

Tags: python, diff

I need to write code in python language for comparing the text of document using fingerprint techniques. I do not know to take fingerprint of a document or to generate fingerprint of a document. I'm asking if anyone knows the method or has source code for generating fingerprints of documents which is stored in bits form.

Comment: edit your tag: you used [pthon] instead of [python]

Answer (score 4):

If you want [message digests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) (cryptographic hashes), use the [hashlib](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-hashlib.html) library. Here's an example ([IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/) session):

```
 In [1]: import hashlib

 In [2]: md = hashlib.sha256(open('/tmp/Calendar.xls', 'rb').read())

 In [3]: md.hexdigest()
 Out[3]: '8517f1eae176f1a20de78d879f81f23de503cfd6b8e4be1d798fb2342934b187'
```

Answer (score 4):

You might try the following papers to get started with the concept of fingerprinting:

- [Winnowing: Local Algorithms for Document Fingerprinting](http://theory.stanford.edu/~aiken/publications/papers/sigmod03.pdf)
- [Scalable Document Fingerprinting](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/user/nch/www/koala/main.html)